# How can i disable auto save & revisions with `function.php` in wordpress?

Tags: functions, revisions, autosave

I need disable auto save & revisions with function.php in wordpress.
What should I do?
thanks

Comment: Welcome! What problem are you trying to solve that removing these fixes? Which editor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);
function disable_autosave() {
    wp_deregister_script('autosave');
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'disable_autosave');
```

Simple method

Comment: Will that work for the block editor?